# Only one active button in React

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a list of buttons. I want to make one of them to have a active state and when that one has every other shouldn't have that state. So styling is applied only to the active one. I almost did it, i mean it change styling when i press on each other but i have no idea how to make it to deactivate a button when i click on another one.

Bellow is my code. props.planets is array of object {id: 'name', title: 'name'}

MenuList it takes a props.planets and generate list of MenuButton components

```js
const MenuList = (props) => {
  return (
    <ul className={classes.planet_list}>
      {props.planets.map((planet) => (
        <MenuButton key={planet.id} title={planet.title}  />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

MenuButton is my button component i want it to have module classes: modulebutton as a main styling, class based on title, and an active class if button is active

```js
const MenuButton = (props) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState();

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setActive({ active: props.title });
  };

  return (
    <li>
      <div
        className={`${classes.menubutton} ${classes[props.title]} ${
          active && classes.active
        }`}
        onClick={clickHandler}
      >
        {props.title}
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the active state in the parent not in the child component

MenuList.js

```
const MenuList = (props) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState();

function activeButton(value){
   setActive(value)
}
  return (
    <ul className={classes.planet_list}>
      {props.planets.map((planet) => (
        <MenuButton onChange={activeButton} disabled={active} key={planet.id} title={planet.title}  />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

MenuButton.js

```
const MenuButton = (props) => {

  const clickHandler = (keyID) => {
    props.onChange(keyID)
  };

  return (
    <li>
      <div
        className={props.active === props.key ? "activeClass" : "inactiveClass"}
        onClick={() => clickHandler(props.key)}
      >
        {props.title}
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};
```

That should be it. May need a useEffect but let me know of any bugs

Answer (score 4):

**One of the easiest solution for an active state on button. For this purpose you need to have an active state.** I hope this would help you!

```js
const {useState,Fragment} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState("");
 
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setActive(event.target.id);
    
  }

    return (
      <Fragment>
      <button
        key={1}
        className={active === "1" ? "active" : undefined}
        id={"1"}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Solution
      </button>

       <button
       key={2}
       className={active === "2" ? "active" : undefined}
       id={"2"}
       onClick={handleClick}
     >
      By
     </button>

      <button
      key={3}
      className={active === "3" ? "active" : undefined}
      id={"3"}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
        Jamal
    </button>
</Fragment>

    );
}


 ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.active{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 <div id="react"></div>
```